# Random order for ArrayCollection in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

Here's part of my `Question` Entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $options;
```

and here's part of the `Answer` Entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="text")
     */
    private $option;
```

Here's the Repository that gets random questions:

```
public function findQuestionsForQuiz($quantity = 0)
    {
        // get the lowest id
        $lowestId = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('q.id')
            ->orderBy('q.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;

        // get the total number of questions
        $totalRows = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('COUNT(q.id)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;
        $randomQuestionIds = $this->uniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($lowestId, $totalRows+$lowestId, $quantity);

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->where('q.id IN(:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', $randomQuestionIds)
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $qb->getResult();
    }
```

While this is working fine, I've been trying to get the Answers to be sorted randomly and am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Why not simply
`$entries = $question->getOptions()->toArray();
shuffle($entries);` ?

Comment: @Matteo, with your suggestion, I loop and questions shuffled the options then add everything into another array for twig.  That works. Thanks

Comment: @Matteo, please make this as an answer so I can mark and accept it. thanks

Comment: hi @shaNnex you are welcome! I post an answer so you can close your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply shuffle the entity related to the answer. As example:

```
$entries = $question->getOptions()->toArray(); 
shuffle($entries);
```

Hope this help